# Merge [m2e] and [m2eclipse] tags

Tags: discussion, status-completed, synonym-request

[m2e](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/m2e) is the renamed version of [m2eclipse](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/m2eclipse). Both terms are used more or synonymously (for the Maven plugin in Eclipse). Should they be merged?

Comment: There is already a suggested synonym for making [tag:m2e] a synonym of [tag:m2eclipse]: http://stackoverflow.com/tags/m2eclipse/synonyms It is pending since 2013... (I already voted on it a long time ago but it is still missing 2 votes).

Answer (score 2):

**Yes, the two tags should be merged.**

Both tags even have the same tag wiki excerpt.

> m2eclipse is a Plug-in for the Eclipse IDE that defines Eclipse
>   Project structures by analyzing Maven Project models.

As Tunaki points out, [there is a pending synonym request](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/m2eclipse/synonyms) to synonymize [m2e](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/m2e) with [m2eclipse](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/m2eclipse) which currently needs 2 more votes.